# Wha't the difference between Channel#write(msg) and Channel#write(msg, promise)?

Tags: netty

I'm reading the Javadoc of Channel of Netty:
http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html

But it doesn't explain anything about the difference between `Channel#write(msg)` and `Channel#write(msg, promise)`. What's the purpose of the `promise` in the 2nd method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChannelPromise is a special writable ChannelFuture which get notified once the IO operation completes.

the method `Channel#write(msg)` will delegate to `Channel#write(msg, promise)` with a `DefaultChannelPromise` created by netty as the second parameter

Comment: So, I can pass my own `Promise` to be notified when the channel write operation flushes to the socket?

Answer (score 1):

A *Promise* is a Future that you can modify; for more information please refer to https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/873